# Delphi + Indy: Connection closed gracefully

Tags: delphi, indy

Using D7 + Indy 10 latest build.

My code is using TIdSMTP to send email. 
I keep getting "Connection closed gracefully" at some end-users, and the email is never sent.

The code is like:

```
try
~~~~
~~~~
_idSMTP := TIdSmtp.Create;
with _idSMTP do
begin
  Host := 'myhost';
  Connect;
  try
    Send(_EmailMsg);
    Result := True;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      MsgDlgErr(Self.Handle, E.Message)
    end
  end;
end;
finally
 _idSMTP.Disconnect;
 _idSMTP.Free;
end;
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 22):

Read all about it on http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showarticle.php?id=1

> EIdConnClosedGracefully is an
>   exception signaling that the
>   connection has been closed by the
>   other side intentionally. This is not
>   the same as a broken connection which
>   would cause a connection reset error.
>   If the other side has closed the
>   connection and the socket is read or
>   written to, EIdConnClosedGracefully
>   will be raised by Indy. This is
>   similar to attempting to read or write
>   to a file that has been closed without
>   your knowledge.
>
> In some cases this is a true exception
>   and your code needs to handle it. In
>   other cases (typically servers) this
>   is a normal part of the functioning of
>   the protocol and Indy handles this
>   exception for you. Even though Indy
>   catches it, when running in the IDE
>   the debugger will be triggered first.
>   You can simply press F9 to continue
>   and Indy will handle the exception,
>   but the constant stopping during
>   debugging can be quite annoying. In
>   the cases where Indy catches the
>   exception, your users will never see
>   an exception in your program unless it
>   is run from the IDE.

Comment: The exception doesn't occur in the IDE, but on end-user computers.

Comment: Some virusscanners block outgoing connections on the SMTP port nowadays. This may cause the connection to be unresponsive and throw this error.

Comment: @Atlas: That is why it says "In some cases..." :) The page also talks about the other cases.

Comment: The server could also be disconnecting the connection on its end if any error is detected in the message data or sender/recipient addresses as well.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was caused because I used a sender email address from a different domain than the one hosted by the smtp server, that's why the smtp server rejected the connection.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, in case of AT&T server, it rejects an email address which is not `@att.net` address in the `MAIL FROM`. More info can be determined by logging the error using `TIdLogEvent` for these users that receive it, otherwise the error report is rather vague - if the disconnect (Connection closed gracefully) occurs right after the `MAIL FROM` then it might indicate a server policy rejecting an email with the domain which it doesn't host as explained by Toni as well.

Otherwise the "Connection closed gracefully" error means that an attempt is being made to read/write to socket that has been closed by the peer **intentionally** - in your case, peer is the SMTP server you connect to. It is different than the "Connection reset" error which indicates a broken connection. In both cases, the connection is no longer present and you can't read/write anymore to it.

Answer (score 1):

We got this error when the OpenSSL libraries hadn't been installed at the client site

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old and so on, but i've done with this exeption already.

In my case, the server was blocking send of mail because I exceeded the daily send limits for the hosting service. It's easy to exceed these limits when testing something. The exception itself is ambiguous, so there may be more reasons, but I would start by checking this issue first. It solved the problem for me.