# Sending mail with delphi (Connection closed Gracefully)

Tags: delphi, email, smtp, gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delphi + Indy: Connection closed gracefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085933/delphi-indy-connection-closed-gracefully)

I want to send some E-mails with delphi, i had this little code :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i : integer;
begin
  IdMsgSend := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
  SSLHandler :=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  try
    with IdMsgSend do
    begin
     ContentType := 'text/plain';
     Body.Text := 'Test test text';
     From.Text := 'USERNAME@gmail.com';
     ReplyTo.EMailAddresses := 'Recipient@server.com';
     Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'Recipient@server.com';
     Subject := 'i just came to say hello';
    end;

    SMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
    try
      SMTP.Username := 'USERNAME@gmail.com';
      SMTP.Password := 'PASSWODD';
      SMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
      SMTP.Port := 465;

      SMTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
      SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
      SMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
      SMTP.Connect;
      try
            IdMsgSend.Body.Text := 'The body';
            IdMsgSend.Subject := 'The subject';
            SMTP.Send(IdMsgSend);
      finally
        SMTP.Disconnect;
      end;

    finally
      FreeAndNil(SMTP);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(IdMsgSend);
  end;
end;
```

It used to work just fine! now, everytime i try to send an email i get this error at the `SMTP.Send(IdMsgSend)` : 
Connection closed Gracefully

I've read that it might be from the antivirus or firewall, so i disabled them both, but still same problem?

What is wrong here? did gmail changed its SMTP options or something like that?

Comment: @jachguate i said i disabled the antivir and the firewall so nothing is blocking, + i tested gmail and hotmail so its not server problem

Comment: I didn't say that something is blocking, it just looks the same question. The server may be closing the connection due to server antivirus or other anti-spam measures. Did you log the transmission? it's always closed at the same point? do you have another computer to compare results?

Comment: @jachguate i said that cuz i already read that question and that's what they answered :/, no i didnt log the transmission, and yea it always closes at the same point, and no i dont have another computer

Comment: Log it, you only will know if it closes at the same point after examining logs for different runs.

Comment: @yassine, don't you want to [`try to authenticate`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11157460/960757) to the server ?

Comment: @jachguate i dont really know how to log the transmission ...

Comment: @TLama it does not want to authenticate :o ...

Comment: @yassine You can use a TIdLogFile and attach it to your TIdSMTP.Intercept property to log the client/server conversation to a file from inside your application. Or you can use Wireshark or other sniffing tools to do that at the machine level.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showarticle.php?id=1), it's an exception that's not correctly handled by Delphi. Try to do the shown modification on your Debugger Options and the problem will be solved.

Comment: followed that article, the error dosnt show up, but the email is not send too