# Getting a lot of "Read timed out" exceptions from Indy's IdTCPServer

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy, gprs

"Read timed out" exception is raising at ReadBytes(B1, 600, False) for 50%  of the connection requests and 20% at ReadBytes(B3, 5, False). So only a few connections finish properly.
I know the process for making 600 bytes at the client side doesn't take more than 2 seconds. By the way there is no improvements in the results if I increase ReadTimeout from 10000 to 20000.
There are about 50 clients which usually connect at diverse day times, so we don't have a crowded server.
My goal by setting ReadTimeout is to close the connection when there are some problems as soon as possible.
Is there any problem with my code or should I search for the problem some where else?

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Log: TConnectionLog;
  B1, B2, B3: TIdBytes;
begin
  try
    try
      Log := TConnectionLog.Create;
      Log.ConnectDateTime := Now;
      Log.ClientIP := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;

      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 10000; 
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(B1, 600, False);
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := IdTimeoutDefault;
      Log.Bytes600ReceiveDateTime := Now;

      SetLength(B2, 200);
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(B2);
      Log.Bytes200SendDateTime := Now;

      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 15000; 
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(B3, 5, False);
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := IdTimeoutDefault;
      Log.Bytes5ReceiveDateTime := Now;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        Log.ExceptionMessage := E.Message;
        raise;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        SaveLog(Log);
      end);
    Log.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Delphi 10.2;
Indy 10.6.2;
Network type: 2G/GPRS

Comment: The `ReadTimeout` is applied as a per-byte timeout, so if you are really getting timeouts then either your reads don't match the client's sends, or your traffic is simply not arriving as expecting. Use a sniffer to double check either way

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your comment, I will try it. Another small problem with the code: what is the correct way to avoid getting "Connection closed gracefully" exception when the client disconnects normally?

Comment: Exceptions are not always errors; that's a basic. You should not think about it as an error. After that, the only thing that I can add is just "documentation" and "look for it". This is a recurrent question (I remember one comment on code done by @RemyLebeau regarding how recurrent this question is). Check http://ww2.indyproject.org/KB/index.html?whydoikeepgettingeidconnc.htm and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085933/delphi-indy-connection-closed-gracefully

Comment: @Thorba: The "Connection closed gracefully" can be raised in the TIdTCPServer.OnException event handler without making any problem but the problem is that it is "sometimes" raised in my try/except block. as the "documentation" says: "...your client has attempted to read or write to the connection.". but I am at the server side and I don't expect it when reading connection. I can ignore it in the code, no problem, but the inconsistent behaviour was suspicious to me because the exception raises in the try/except block "sometimes".

Comment: @hsn `EIdConnClosedGracefully` is normal behavior on the server side, you are not supposed to avoid it. If you catch it, simply don't log it, but don't discard it. Let it escape `OnExecute` so `TIdTCPServer` can handle it to cleanup the calling thread properly (otherwise, you have to close the connection manually). You are doing the right thing to re-`raise` a caught exception, that is the preferred action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the guidance from Remy Lebeau, I did some network traffic monitoring for many days and found out the problem is raised from the low quality of network in which TCP segments with size of bigger than 100 bytes are getting lost most of the times!